# If statement produces a null result in Java

Tags: java

I don't want to add all of the code as it is a game i am making currently. Anyways, I declared class_Selection, and Characterclass. The user enters a string for class_Selection. 
It displays the result and then proceeds into an if statement in which it uses that same input to decide on what to do afterwards. I am very new to java, and coding for that matter and this is my first project. The problem is probably simple. As you can see I placed it in all caps because I heard that if its in all caps no matter how the user enters it, it will accept that key, such as: MeLeE, That may not be true.
The result produces as it goes through the rest of the program correctly even displays the results for class_Selection but when it gets to the if- statements it displays null.

*Edit*
The problem is somehow character class is equal to null so when I 
System.out.println(Characterclass);
I am receiving null.

I fixed the ==, thank you for that, but I need to fix CharacterClass somehow ending up to be null.

*EDIT* The problem was, in the IF-statement I had the answer in all caps, I know there is probably a way to do that, but I wasn't doing it right. If I enter the right key such as if it is MELEE, I enter MELEE it will display the results. Also I think when I did the 
system.out.println(Characterclass); , I didn't have a method that ran it so I am going to fix that. I got it to display the bonuses.

Thank you for the == problem, I am a step farther on my goal.

// Class Selection

```
    System.out.println("Which one did you excel in ( Class )? Melee, Magic, or Archery?"); // Class selection
    String class_Selection; // Hold the class name (make method with this to declare bonuses and things that have to do with the class he chose: such as If ( class_Selection == melee) 
    class_Selection = classSelection.next(); // User enters name of class they want
    System.out.println("You entered: " + class_Selection + (" Is this the class you want?, y or n?"));

    String yOrN;
    yOrN = defaultScanner.next();

    if (yOrN == "n") { // redo if selection is no
        System.out.println("Then which class would you like? Melee, Magic, Archery?");
        class_Selection = classSelection.next();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + class_Selection + (" Is this the class you want?, y or n?"));
        yOrN = defaultScanner.next();


    }else{ // Does nothing if y because the selection is correct
    }

    // Continue after class selection


        System.out.println("Your class is: " + class_Selection); // Final display
        System.out.println("\n");


        // This is where your selection takes effect and displays your bonuses

        if (class_Selection == "MELEE") {
            Characterclass = "melee";
            System.out.println("Melee = +5 Blade, +5 Blunt, +5 Hand-To-Hand, +5 Heavy Armor,");

        }
        if (class_Selection == "ARCHERY") {
            Characterclass = "Archery";
            System.out.println("+10 Archery, + 10 Light Armor");

        }
        if (class_Selection == "MAGIC") {
            Characterclass = "Magic";
            System.out.println(" +10 Arcane, +5 Light Armor");


}
        System.out.println(Characterclass);

}
```

}

Comment: I don't think your CharacterClass is defined in the scope of the print statement

Comment: This kind of questions (`==` instead of `equals`) is asked at least 20 times a day.

Comment: Why don't you use an enum for your classes (not a must, just a suggestion)?

Comment: Efficient debugging is the second most valuable skill two a programmer, second only to initially writing correct & clean code.

Comment: Check out `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: Tried fixing Characterclass in the scope as you said awash, but its still producing null even with the == fix.

Answer (score 2):

`if (yOrN == "n")`!!! should be  `if (yOrN.equals("n")){...}`

For  any `Object` equality check, you should use `Object#equals`. For Object reference equality check you should use `==`

Comment: Produces same results, did this to all of the strings in the if statement.

Comment: Thank you for that, but that wasn't the problem, just a problem lol. Can you read my edit please?

Comment: `System.out.println(Characterclass);` here what is `Characterclass`???

Comment: Sorry I fixed it, and it was declared in an area I didn't paste. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing Strings in Java, use `String.equals()`; not == operator. e.g. `yOrN.equals("n")`

The `==` operator checks to see if the two Strings reference the same String object. The `equals()` method compares if two Strings have the same characters within both Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Compare Strings using `.equals()`, not using `==`  which compares references. If you want a case insensitive comparison use `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Answer (score 0):

Comparison of `Strings` should be done using **equals**

```
if (yOrN == "n") {
// Code
}
```

Will become

```
if (yOrN.equlals("n")) {
// Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (yOrN.equals("n"))
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) about how to compare Strings.